# How to list subcategories on category page in big-commerce ( blueprint )?

Tags: bigcommerce

I am using Classic next theme
For stencil I have a below code but this is not working in blue print.

```
{{#each categories}}
    {{#if ../breadcrumbs.[1].name  '===' name}}
        {{#if children}}
            <h5>{{name}}</h5>
            <ul class="navList">
            {{#each children}}
                <li class="navList-item">
                    <a class="navList-action" href="{{url}}" alt="{{name}}" title="{{name}}">{{name}}</a>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: Blueprint themes don't support handlebars. Here's a link to the documentation for Blueprint themes: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/blueprint/

Comment: blueprint not support stencil concepts ...!

Comment: Can any body let me know the code to show list of sub category on category page for blue print themes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be different depending on what specific Blueprint theme you are using but, I would try using the "%%SNIPPET_SubCategories%%" variable inside of the "category.html" file.